# Dart Angular and mySql

Tags: mysql, angular, dart

I'm starting to build a new version of web application migrating to a very old php+html code to Angular Dart. I use Dart for daily work so I'm familiar with it, while I'm not familiar to Angular.
The old school website used mySql as DB to store data, so I would love to avoid a complete migration to a new DB if possible, but I'm facing a problem.

**mysql1** I guess is incompatible with Angular, since when compile I get this error:

```
[WARNING] build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart: Skipping compiling WHLivePortal|web/main.dart with ddc because some of its
transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform:
mysql1|lib/src/buffered_socket.dart
mysql1|lib/src/buffer.dart
mysql1|lib/src/single_connection.dart
```

**SQLJocky** is incompatible with dart 2

Which path can I follow to step forward?

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you asking for a browser DB (Web SQL, Indexed DB) or a regular MySQL DB for server